# As the project manager, what to do when an engineer decided on 'wrong' decision?

Tags: project-management

I'm new as a consultant and project manager. In my role as I understood it, I was not responsible (or even has the right) to decide on technical decision, it was engineer's. I only know a little bit, but don't think I'm an expert, so it's all good.

I was assigned in the middle of a project. In this project, I noticed that the database structure is (in my opinion) not properly normalized, and to fix this another table must be formed. This is not the only 'problem' I've found and in my opinion we should remap based on the master data provided by the client.

I can help with the remap and I don't think I'll have an issue convincing the engineer.

I am instead concerned that this will create dependence on other's 'expertise' on future projects and prevent their growth. I am also concerned with deadline. I can go on with the remap, or turn a blind eye and let this project has suboptimal data structure (which I'm also concerned will cause issues later).

**I'm not sure how to proceed from here. What should I do? What can I do to mitigate those concerns?**

Update context: this engineer is a junior engineer, which why I am concerned about their growth. Two others senior engineer also independently state the need to step back and remap, which confirm my observation and thus putting me in my 'dillema'. They help in this project now.

In hindsight, with a clearer mind now I can see that it won't prevent their growth, but instead teach them the proper way (as long as you tell them why it should be done *this* way).

Comment: Can you come up with a cost to fix it now versus a cost to work around the technical debt every time a query has to be written in a more complicated way in the future?

Comment: Suboptimal data structures exist all over the place. As long as there isn't a problem with storage that a bigger disk can't fix, don't worry about it. Database normalization was an issue when disks were small but not now in most cases. We can cause more problems by trying to make everything perfect now instead of getting a project done.

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes. The end of first phase of project is near, so the remap will cost us delay in completing the first phase, but save us time during the next phases.

Comment: If you are the project manage, and you are willing to a hit to the schedule, just assign the senior engineers to the remap and move forward.  You most certainly should NOT use the junior engineer to fix their own mistakes. I also honestly don't understand your question.  If you don't have a senior engineer who can handle the task, you will have to decide, which is word the potential technical debt in the future or the schedule hit that most certainly will happen due to the inexperience of the junior engineer.

Comment: @Donald these senior engineers were not in my team. Later after I asked this, they became free and can help, which they do the remap.

Answer (score 9):

If you're unsure on something a technical expert has done or is doing, ask them about it. There may be underlying reasons something is done a certain way, or you may have incomplete information.

Your task is to manage the project, worrying about future technical reliance on you is a waste of effort. If anything it would make you a more valuable employee. If an engineer is incompetent, you don't take over their role, you hire a competent engineer.

I'm not saying the engineer is incompetent. There are a myriad of reasons why projects can end up with suboptimal ways of solving problems. Especially if they have evolved from the original specifications.

Answer (score 8):

## You're blowing this way out of proportion

One single instance of a technical course correction is not going to make your engineers dependent on you to make technical decisions in the future. It might be that future engineers need to reference the specifics in how it was implemented, in which case, you *document, document, document.*

As for your deadlines, that's something only you and your team can answer as to whether it will be doable on time and at the cost of what other functionality that is still to be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

No offence, but as a Project Manager your job is to make sure the project is done on time and on budget, not making technical changes

Any 'expertise' you want to provide in any other areas are at your discretion, and it is at engineer decision to accept or ignore it

Your current view on the data structure may well be out of context, perhaps its already been changed several times due to customer requirement change requests